# How do I use a Shopify App to modify the Admin area in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am currently developing a Shopify App and at the moment, it only makes use of the Storefront API. I want my app to also make modifications to the Admin Area, specifically in a similar way that the Metafield Guru App adds a tab at product level, and allows you to go into the metafields of a certain product and make changes to them.

[Metafields Guru App Tab at Product Level in Admin Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms8Ly.png)

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction for this, as I am trying to create a similar feature in which the user can access other properties for the productt.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is configured in the Shopify Partner account for the APP.

There is option where you can create Admin Links when you install the App. It's not code related, it's just Shopify feature for Apps. More info in here: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-an-admin-link-to-the-shopify-admin-with-app-extensions

There is no other way to modify the admin area (with code) since Shopify back-end is a closed platform and you don't have access to modify it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've got the Admin Link working!. Just to go one deeper, are you aware of any way that I can set it so that this Admin Link is only enabled on certain products? Ideally via code but if this is not possible then no worries

Comment: @RyanDawkes no, you don't have control over it with code and you can't disable/enable it only on specific products.